# Dynamic SQL queries with Power Query Dates

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerquery

I am trying to builds Dynamic SQL queries with Power Query with cell value
I input Values on tables and drill down to get single value and edit in in source of query

Like this one

```
and day_date >= '"&StartDate&"' and day_date <= '"&EndDate&"'
group by trim(m.[first_name]) +' '+ trim(m.[last_name]),  trim(e.[first_name]) +' '+ trim(e.[last_name])
```

And value

[image]

But I keep getting an error in SQL Query

```
DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SQL
    DataSourcePath=*********;*********
    Message=Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
    ErrorCode=-2146232060
    Number=241
    Class=16
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory? Somewhere you are attempting to convert a string to a datetime and the format is wrong.

Comment: I know but when using same format in SQL Server or just replace StartDate and EndDate with 2021-11-13 it is run normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I replaced "' with '"

```
and day_date >= '"&StartDate&"' and day_date <= '"&EndDate&"'
```

The correct code

```
and day_date >= "'&StartDate&'" and day_date <= "'&EndDate&'"
```